# Test Class for AggregateResult as parameter

Tags: apex, class

I have a class called MyClass with the below code.

```
public with sharing class MyClass{
// some code

 public static String getName(String criteria, AggregateResult aggrResult, String apiName){
//some code
}

}
```

I am trying to write a test class for it. But I don't know what parameter I need to pass at AggregateResult place.

below is the test class which I am trying from my side.
Test Class line:

```
MyClass.getName('Name:Test','8.00','TRHC__Time__c'); // it's currently giving error to me
```

Aggregateresult is not String/decimal. So Please let me know what I need to pass in that place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an AggregateResult; this means you'll need to actually perform a query and get some result back, then you can process it.

Comment: My Bad.. created a query and worked fine.. Sorry for asking :)